# Edit menu in web view not being displayed for first time.

Tags: ios, menu, edit

My app downloads manual from server. After opening th annual for the first time tap and hold on word selects the word but does not display edit menu

CanPerformAction: delegate not being called for the first time selection. From second time tap and hold it displays edit menu and works as usual. 
Once i go back and reopen the manual  , i have the same problem

Any help appreciated
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Working fine after adding the following method

```
 -(BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder
 {
   return YES;
 }
```